# Powershell parsing system.array - netsh wlan show profiles

Tags: powershell, automation, scripting, system.array

I'm trying to automate getting WiFi name & password.
My biggest issue is parsing the output in system.array format. Since I can't simply access the value by its key. I'm loking for a way to make sure the parsing is not going to brake if run on a different PC.

```
> $all_profiles = netsh wlan show profile
> $all_profiles
Profiles on interface Wi-Fi:

Group policy profiles (read only)
---------------------------------
<None>

User profiles
-------------
All User Profile     : GRUBISIC
All User Profile     : HUAWEI
All User Profile     : A1
All User Profile     : Ma
All User Profile     : Ka
All User Profile     : Ou
All User Profile     : GK_Si
All User Profile     : 93
All User Profile     : 9B
All User Profile     : Li
All User Profile     : A
All User Profile     : NETI
All User Profile     : Re
All User Profile     : Chu

> $all_profiles.GetType()
IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType                                                                                                                                                                                                            
-------- -------- ----                                     --------                                                                                                                                                                                                            
True     True     Object[]                                 System.Array
```

For now I'd like to parse it into the list of profle names, so: [GRUBISIC, HUAWEI ...]

[Output of netsh commands](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mvFdC.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below works for me, there most likely is a fully PowerShell cmdlet to replace this but not sure which one :)

```
$all_profiles | Select-String 'All User Profile' | ForEach-Object {
    $_ -replace '(?<=\S)\s+:\s+(?=\S)','=' | ConvertFrom-StringData
}
```

See https://regex101.com/r/mOtSHS/1 for reference.